# Delete An NSMutableArray from another Class in C-Objective?

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I need help with delete an array with a button from the SecondViewController in the view controller class.

At the moment I have this:

```
- (IBAction)deleteArrayFromSeconViewController:(id)sender  // is the Button which should                           
                                                           // delete the array
{
    self.textLabel2.text = @"";                            // this work fine
    ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    [vc.textViewArray removeAllObjects];                   // do not remove the objects?

}
```

What should I do to overtake an order from the SecondViewControllerClass in the ViewControllerClass?

I tried also this in the SecondViewControllerClass:

```
- (IBAction)deleteArrayFromSeconViewController:(id)sender 
{
    self.textLabel2.text = @"";

    ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    [vc deleteTheArray];

}
```

to call this function in the ViewControllerClass:

```
- (void) deleteTheArray
{
    [textViewArray removeAllObjects];
}
```

Comment: you probably need a pointer to a currently existing "another view controller" rather than creating the new one.

Comment: It may also be worthwhile to make a method on the other ViewController that you call to clear the array, so that it can choose to run any housekeeping code, instead of having the data pulled out from under it. Even if there's no housekeeping necessary now, it would make future refactoring easier :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not at all sure that this is the best way to do this, but you could post a custom `NSNotification` in your first view controller, and then pick it up in your second. Code Example:

```
//Post in your first view controller when wanting to delete the array
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DeleteArrayNotification" object:nil userInfo:nil /*include any items your reciever might wish to access*/];
```

and then in your second view controller, you could add yourself as an observer in the `-(void)awakeFromNib` Method. Put in your awake from nib method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(deleteArrayNotification:) name:@"DeleteArrayNotification" object:nil];
```

And then implement the deleteArrayNotification: method:

```
- (void)deleteArrayNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
[array removeAllObjects];
[array release]; //Delete this line if your project is using ARC
}
```

I am highly doubtful that this is good coding practice to implement `NSNotification` like this, but I thought it might be of use!

More information can be found under the Apple developer documentation, under `NSNotification` and `NSNotificationCenter`.

Hope I can help!

Ben